# Is there a more efficient way to write my filters in this specific context?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, unpivot

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and I have a table (`t1`) in my database which contains a list of numbers (n1 to n6). An extract is given below:

```
Id   n1   n2   n3   n4   n5   n6
100  3    10   26   31   35   39
101  1    3    11   22   36   40
102  10   19   20   30   39   40
103  6    12   25   27   28   33
...
```

Assuming I want to filter out this table by excluding rows where numbers 3 and 19 exist, my filtering codes would look like this:

```
Select * from t1

WHERE [n1] not in (3,19)
AND [n2] not in (3,19)
AND [n3] not in (3,19)
AND [n4] not in (3,19)
AND [n5] not in (3,19)
AND [n6] not in (3,19)
```

Expected Output:

```
Id   n1   n2   n3   n4   n5   n6
103  6    12   25   27   28   33
...
```

Is there a more efficient way to write my filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option uses `not exists` and `values()`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1
    from (values(n1), (n2), (n3), (n4), (n5), (n6)) x(n)
    where n in (3, 19)
)
```

This scales better than you original query when the number of columns and/or values in the list increases - although this will not necessarily be more efficient.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0ecd99f97085fdd650964f359ca056e0)**:

```
 Id | n1 | n2 | n3 | n4 | n5 | n6
--: | -: | -: | -: | -: | -: | -:
103 |  6 | 12 | 25 | 27 | 28 | 33
```

Answer (score 1):

Your filter is fine, but you might find it simpler to write as:

```
where 3 not in (n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6) and
      19 not in (n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6)
```

Because you are referencing all six columns with inequalities, you cannot really improve the performance.  You *could* fix the data model so the columns are in separate rows -- allowing an index to be used.

Answer (score 0):

**Place the Set of Values not Wanted in a CTE and Use the Except Operator**

As others have noted, the data model is less than ideal.

To work around the `NOT IN` filter inefficiencies, you could use the EXCEPT operator like this:

```
--sample data
   WITH smple ( id, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6) AS
    ( SELECT 100, 3, 10, 26, 31, 35, 39
    union all
    select 101,1,3,11,22,36,40
    union all
    select
    102,10,19,20,30,39,40
    union all
    select
    103,6,12,25,27,28,33
    ),
--end sample data
    not_vals (n) as (select 3 union all select 19 ) 
    SELECT
        s.*
    FROM
        smple s
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT
        s.*
    FROM
        smple s join not_vals nv on
                nv.n IN ( s.n1, s.n2, s.n3, s.n4, s.n5, s.n6)
     ;
```

It would be interesting to look at the efficiency of the various approaches one can use from a performance perspective.

---

The final solution should have good performance, so a correlated subquery probably will not provide that.

Here is a correlated subquery:

```
--sample data
with smple ( id, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6) AS
( SELECT 100, 3, 10, 26, 31, 35, 39
union all
select 101,1,3,11,22,36,40
union all
select
102,10,19,20,30,39,40
union all
select
103,6,12,25,27,28,33
),
--end sample data
not_vals (n) as (select 3 union all select 19 ) 
SELECT
    s.*
FROM
    smple s
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM not_vals nv
        WHERE
            nv.n IN ( s.n1, s.n2, s.n3, s.n4, s.n5, s.n6)
    )
;
```